# Issues with ContentDialog and x:Bind

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a `ContentDialog` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I have a `TextBox` with its Text property bound via `x:Bind` syntax to a string property on my code-behind.

If I edit the contents of the `TextBox`, and then click on another control in the `ContentDialog` (losing focus on the `TextBox`), and then click on the primary button, by the time I get to the primary button click event handler the text property has been updated with the content of the `TextBox` control = PERFECT.

However, if I change the contents of the `TextBox` but then keep it in focus and THEN click on the primary button the binding never gets updated.

It seems that the reason for this is because the built-in buttons in `ContentDialog` do not acquire focus before their click eventhandlers are fired, and as `x:Bind` only supports `LostFocus` binding, these bindings will never be updated.

I'm staggered that this big bug exists. So my 2 questions are

1) Is there a workaround

2) Do I have to abandon `x:Bind` and use WPF-style `Binding` syntax, where I can change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` within the binding itself.

I'm hoping that another UWP dev has come across this and knows of a work around

**EDIT**

Ive created some example code to demonstrate the issue.

page:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Content="Open" Click="OpenClick" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void OpenClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new ContentDialog1();
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

content dialog:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="App1.ContentDialog1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TITLE"
    PrimaryButtonText="Button1"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Path=TestText, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="100"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

content dialog code behind:

```
public sealed partial class ContentDialog1 : ContentDialog, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ContentDialog1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string _testText;
    public string TestText
    {
        get => _testText;
        set
        {
            _testText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TestText));
        }
    }

    private void ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And my target sdk verions are:

[image]

If you click open the content dialog, enter some text, then click the primary button - if you have a breakpoint in the click handler you'll see that the binding hasn't updated with your entered text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've looked into this, and have tested this on all SDK's back to build 10586. Essentially `ContentDialog` is broken for `x:Bind` bindings to `TextBox`, because `TextBox` is required to lose focus in order for its bindings to update. 
I have tried a number of hacks including walking the visual tree on `Loaded` to add extra handlers to the hidden buttons, and trying to force them to focus (thus removing focus from any `TextBox`, and triggering the binding update) before the click handler fires, but without UWP supporting the tunnelling event strategy (like WPF), it is not possible to inject any kind of event handling between the button press and the hard-wired click handler running.
The upshot is that `x:Bind` (which doesn't support `UpdateSourceTrigger` other than `LostFocus`) cannot reliably work in `ContentDialog` with `TextBox` controls.

I have logged a bug at Microsoft uservoice.

The only way to solve this is to abandon `x:Bind` and use classic Bindings which support an `UpdateSourceTrigger` of `PropertyChanged` - thus allowing bindings to be always up-to-date before the button in clicked.
But even this is a hack, because `UpdateSourceTrigger` of `PropertyChanged` will cause unnecessary updates in your setters - which can be problematic. Also updating setters in `INotifyPropertyChanged` will fire many additional rounds of the arrange/measure pass for all of your layout.

The only real solution is to write your own `ContentDialog` control. I was tempted to do this, but without access to Microsofts source code for these controls, it's difficult to know if you have done it successfully

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the issue: the setter of `string` property in code-behind is always fired before the `ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick`, even if I click the primary button while the focus is still on the `TextBox`. My sample (tested on Fall Creators Update):

*MyContentDialog.xaml*

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{x:Bind MyString, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

*MyContentDialog.xaml.cs*

```
public sealed partial class MyContentDialog : ContentDialog, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DTO dto;

    private string myString;
    public string MyString
    {
        get
        {
            return myString;
        }
        set
        {
            myString = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MyString));
        }
    }

    public MyContentDialog(DTO dto)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.dto = dto;
        MyString = dto.text;
    }


    private void ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
        dto.text = MyString;
    }

    private void ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

*DTO.cs*

```
public class DTO
{
    public string text;
}
```

*MainPage.xaml.cs*

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DTO dto = new DTO { text = "My text" };

    MyContentDialog dialog = new MyContentDialog(dto);
    await dialog.ShowAsync();

    await new MessageDialog("My text, after being edited by the user in MyContentDialog: " + dto.text).ShowAsync();
}
```

Could you share your code? What's the min and target version of your project?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Have created a version of my code that exhibits this issue, and included target SDK info

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out I spent a lot of time just like you did almost two days failed and Content Dialog crashes my application if there is null object binding to any of the control have to use Converters.

I was just thinking how about placing a usercontrol on the dialog and see if the binding works.

Let me try post the results here.

If you have figured out any other way of doing this let me know